# Структура SPA приложения

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, spa

совсем недавно решил познакомиться с Vue.js и соответственно с созданием одно-страничного приложения. В связи с этим возник ряд вопросов, так раньше работал только с MPA с использованием jQuery и там я четко себе представлял структуру, ну к примеру файл страницы html, к нему отдельный файл со скриптами и отдельный со стилями, ну и общие файлы со скриптами и со стилями. Ну а теперь собственно о вопросах которые у меня возникли:

Как структурировано SPa приложение? На сколько я видел, что в файл с компонентом помещается html разметка, стили и скрипты этого компонента... Но к примеру у меня выходит по 100-150 строк кода CSS, HTML, Vue.js это не слишком ли большое нагромождение? И что касается общих стилей они же должны выноситься в отдельный разделяемый файл?

При использование vue-router стили отделены от каждого компонента или пересекаются друг с другом? К примеру если у меня и в одном и другом компоненте есть класс text и в одном компоненте у него цвет красный а в другом черный, данный свойства пересекутся или нет?

Есть у меня имеются небольшие компоненты к примеры всплывающие окна авторизация, стоит ли их выносить в отдельный компонент, либо стоит совмещать с другими где они используются?

К примеру у менять есть четыре страницы у первых двух одинаковый футер и шапка и в других двух тоже одниковый, также в первой странице присутствуеет всплывающая форма авторизации, на сколько компонентом это все примерно нужно разбить?

Хотелось бы получить внятный ответ по поводу структуры SPA приложение желательно с использованием Vue, конечно же с затрагиванием моих вопросов. За ранее спасибо...

Comment: если вам понравился мой ответ, то поставьте пожалуйста зеленую галочку

Comment: Конечно, информация полезная для меня, но вопрос не был раскрыт в полной мере... Поэтому просто голос за.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Вы можете разделить компоненты на компоненты. Это сократит ваш код.
- Если вы в каком-то компоненте в тэг `style` добавите атрибут `scoped`, то стили будут действовать только на тот компонент. А без `scoped` эти стили будут общими для всех компонентов.
- Вам следует создавать отдельный компонент тогда, когда вам нужно использовать его несколько раз. Это сократит ваш код.

P.S. Ответы на все эти вопросы вы можете найти в документации официального сайта [`Vue.js`](https://vuejs.org/)